# Change password without entering current one on My account > edit account in WooCommerce

Tags: wordpress, templates, woocommerce, passwords, wordpress-hook

I would like to disable the "current password" field when a user tries to change their password. Often users have difficulty with passwords, when forgotten it is not possible to ask for the current password.

The user edit form is this: *https://woocommerce.github.io/code-reference/files/woocommerce-templates-myaccount-form-edit-account.html*

I tried deleting the content relating to line 50 to 53 which would be the current password field, but this is not enough, the current password is still needed.

Then I thought about working around the required attribute but it doesn't exist in the form, apparently wordpress asks for validation in another way.

How could the problem be solved?

---

**Template name**: form-edit-account.php

```
<?php
/**
 * Edit account form
 *
 * This template can be overridden by copying it to yourtheme/woocommerce/myaccount/form-edit-account.php.
 *
 * HOWEVER, on occasion WooCommerce will need to update template files and you
 * (the theme developer) will need to copy the new files to your theme to
 * maintain compatibility. We try to do this as little as possible, but it does
 * happen. When this occurs the version of the template file will be bumped and
 * the readme will list any important changes.
 *
 * @see https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/template-structure/
 * @package WooCommerce\Templates
 * @version 3.5.0
 */

defined( 'ABSPATH' ) || exit;

do_action( 'woocommerce_before_edit_account_form' ); ?>

<form class="woocommerce-EditAccountForm edit-account" action="" method="post" <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_edit_account_form_tag' ); ?> >

    <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_edit_account_form_start' ); ?>

    <p class="woocommerce-form-row woocommerce-form-row--first form-row form-row-first">
        <label for="account_first_name"><?php esc_html_e( 'First name', 'woocommerce' ); ?>&nbsp;<span class="required">*</span></label>
        <input type="text" class="woocommerce-Input woocommerce-Input--text input-text" name="account_first_name" id="account_first_name" autocomplete="given-name" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $user->first_name ); ?>" />
    </p>
    <p class="woocommerce-form-row woocommerce-form-row--last form-row form-row-last">
        <label for="account_last_name"><?php esc_html_e( 'Last name', 'woocommerce' ); ?>&nbsp;<span class="required">*</span></label>
        <input type="text" class="woocommerce-Input woocommerce-Input--text input-text" name="account_last_name" id="account_last_name" autocomplete="family-name" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $user->last_name ); ?>" />
    </p>
    <div class="clear"></div>

    <p class="woocommerce-form-row woocommerce-form-row--wide form-row form-row-wide">
        <label for="account_display_name"><?php esc_html_e( 'Display name', 'woocommerce' ); ?>&nbsp;<span class="required">*</span></label>
        <input type="text" class="woocommerce-Input woocommerce-Input--text input-text" name="account_display_name" id="account_display_name" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $user->display_name ); ?>" /> <span><em><?php esc_html_e( 'This will be how your name will be displayed in the account section and in reviews', 'woocommerce' ); ?></em></span>
    </p>
    <div class="clear"></div>

    <p class="woocommerce-form-row woocommerce-form-row--wide form-row form-row-wide">
        <label for="account_email"><?php esc_html_e( 'Email address', 'woocommerce' ); ?>&nbsp;<span class="required">*</span></label>
        <input type="email" class="woocommerce-Input woocommerce-Input--email input-text" name="account_email" id="account_email" autocomplete="email" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $user->user_email ); ?>" />
    </p>

    <fieldset>
        <legend><?php esc_html_e( 'Password change', 'woocommerce' ); ?></legend>

        <p class="woocommerce-form-row woocommerce-form-row--wide form-row form-row-wide">
            <label for="password_current"><?php esc_html_e( 'Current password (leave blank to leave unchanged)', 'woocommerce' ); ?></label>
            <input type="password" class="woocommerce-Input woocommerce-Input--password input-text" name="password_current" id="password_current" autocomplete="off" />
        </p>
        <p class="woocommerce-form-row woocommerce-form-row--wide form-row form-row-wide">
            <label for="password_1"><?php esc_html_e( 'New password (leave blank to leave unchanged)', 'woocommerce' ); ?></label>
            <input type="password" class="woocommerce-Input woocommerce-Input--password input-text" name="password_1" id="password_1" autocomplete="off" />
        </p>
        <p class="woocommerce-form-row woocommerce-form-row--wide form-row form-row-wide">
            <label for="password_2"><?php esc_html_e( 'Confirm new password', 'woocommerce' ); ?></label>
            <input type="password" class="woocommerce-Input woocommerce-Input--password input-text" name="password_2" id="password_2" autocomplete="off" />
        </p>
    </fieldset>
    <div class="clear"></div>

    <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_edit_account_form' ); ?>

    <p>
        <?php wp_nonce_field( 'save_account_details', 'save-account-details-nonce' ); ?>
        <button type="submit" class="woocommerce-Button button" name="save_account_details" value="<?php esc_attr_e( 'Save changes', 'woocommerce' ); ?>"><?php esc_html_e( 'Save changes', 'woocommerce' ); ?></button>
        <input type="hidden" name="action" value="save_account_details" />
    </p>

    <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_edit_account_form_end' ); ?>
</form>

<?php do_action( 'woocommerce_after_edit_account_form' ); ?>
```

Comment: Tbh, you shouldn't remove it. It's there for a reason. It's better to teach people to use proper password managers to generate and remember their passwords for them than it is to make the application less secure.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, I appreciate it. But if a user forgets the password and is returned to his account with a link, how does he change the password if he does not know the previous one ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note: as indicated it is better not to make any changes as this will make the application less secure. However, to answer your question:

While the output from the current password field can be easily modified by overwriting the template file, the **validation is hard coded** and can be found in the [/includes/class-wc-form-handler.php](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/3611d4643791bad87a0d3e6e73e031bb80447417/plugins/woocommerce/includes/class-wc-form-handler.php) file.

To bypass the validation we have to pass 2 error messages, namely:

- Please enter your current password
- Your current password is incorrect

**To get around this**, we are not going to use the real current password, but we are going to create/add **extra custom data, and on that basis allow the user to change his password.**

---

**1)** To bypass the first notice you will have to overwrite the [/myaccount/form-edit-account.php](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/trunk/plugins/woocommerce/templates/myaccount/form-edit-account.php) template file.

Replace line 50 - 53 @version 3.5.0

```html
<p class="woocommerce-form-row woocommerce-form-row--wide form-row form-row-wide">
    <label for="password_current"><?php esc_html_e( 'Current password (leave blank to leave unchanged)', 'woocommerce' ); ?></label>
    <input type="password" class="woocommerce-Input woocommerce-Input--password input-text" name="password_current" id="password_current" autocomplete="off" />
</p>
```

With

```php
<?php
// Get userID
$user_id = $user->ID;

// Generate salt
$salt = md5( openssl_random_pseudo_bytes( 32, $cstrong ) . wp_generate_password( 32, true, true ) );
$enc = $user_id . '::' . crypt( $user_id, $salt );

// NOT empty
if ( ! empty ( $enc ) ) {
    update_user_meta( $user_id, '_enc', $enc );
}

// Encodes data with MIME base64
$value = base64_encode( $enc );

// NOT empty
if ( ! empty ( $value ) ) {
    ?>
    <input type="hidden" name="password_current" id="password_current" value="<?php echo $value; ?>" />
    <?php
} else {
    ?>
    <p class="woocommerce-form-row woocommerce-form-row--wide form-row form-row-wide">
        <label for="password_current"><?php esc_html_e( 'Current password (leave blank to leave unchanged)', 'woocommerce' ); ?></label>
        <input type="password" class="woocommerce-Input woocommerce-Input--password input-text" name="password_current" id="password_current" autocomplete="off" />
    </p>
    <?php
}
?>
```

This will replace the current password field with a hidden input field with a specified value. This value is based on the current `userID` and a salt, which is then saved as `user_meta` when the page is requested.

---

**2)** To bypass the second notification, you can use the [check_password()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/check_password/) WordPress filter hook

```php
/**
 * Filters whether the plaintext password matches the encrypted password.
 *
 * @since 2.5.0
 *
 * @param bool       $check    Whether the passwords match.
 * @param string     $password The plaintext password.
 * @param string     $hash     The hashed password.
 * @param string|int $user_id  User ID. Can be empty.
 */
function filter_check_password( $check, $password, $hash, $user_id ) {
    // Only for WooCommerce edit-account endpoint
    if ( ! is_wc_endpoint_url( 'edit-account' ) ) return $check;

    // Get meta
    $enc = get_user_meta( $user_id, '_enc', true );

    // NOT empty
    if ( ! empty ( $enc ) ) {
        // Get parts
        $parts = explode( '::', base64_decode( $password ) );

        // Compare user ID and data
        if ( $parts[0] == $user_id && str_contains( $enc, $parts[1] ) ) {
            $check = true;
        }
    }
    
    return $check;
}
add_filter( 'check_password', 'filter_check_password', 10, 4 );
```

This will ensure that instead of using the real current password (which is encrypted), our custom `user_meta` is used. When it matches, we allow to change the password